# Zero conversion in sql

Tags: oracle

Char convertion in Oracle have a pattern: to_char(number,'pattern') and provide option "s" to take sign to result, for ex: `select to_char(10,'S999') from dual;` will return `+10`, but when i check `select to_char(0,'S999') from dual;` it return `+0`
Anyone could explain why :-)

Comment: Seems that you mixed up [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) and [`TO_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm) in your question.

Comment: @ThinkJet You right, sorry for my mistake, could you explain why :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happens because `s` specifier makes presence of sign mandatory and places it on specified position.  Even you can put sign as last symbol in string, look at [number format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570) or just try:

```
select
  to_char(10,'S999')  "10 S999",
  to_char(-10,'S999') "-10 S999",
  to_char(0,'S999')   "0 S999",
  to_char(10,'999S')  "10 999S",
  to_char(-10,'999S') "-10 999S",
  to_char(0,'999S')   "0 999S"
from dual
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13153)

According to documentation:

> Negative return values automatically contain a leading negative sign
>   and positive values automatically contain a leading space unless the
>   format model contains the MI, S, or PR format element.

you always get a "minus" char for negative values at start of a string, so there are no need for `S` format specifier at most of the cases.
But if you need for some purpose to always place a sign before or after digits, then you can use `S` format specifier.

If you ask "why `+0` and not `-0`" - it's just "by design" :)

**Update**
And some words about "design":

A long time ago  *(far far away ... :) )* Oracle decide to use special values of data types to indicate null values. For character data it's empty string (that's also [source of two string types - `varchar` and `varchar2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203536/232279)) and for numeric types it's `-0` value.

If you look at specification of [computer number format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format) you can find, that for a signed number one bit always reserved to store sign. Zero value of this bit treated as '+' and value 1 as `-`.
Two representations of zero `-0` and `+0` are same from the point of view of math and one of them can be eliminated without loosing any functionality. So, Oracle designers decide to always store zero value as `+0` and treat `-0` as `null`.
May be behavior changed in modern versions of Oracle, but for compatibility reasons zero value normalization remains unchanged till today and you always got `+0` in string representation.

Comment: Thank for your answer, It isn't the first time i get the answer `by design` :-)

Comment: @HappyGirl Ok, answer updated with design explanation, but I'am not an Oracle designer :-)

Comment: @ThinkJet do you have a source for the information on Oracle storing numeric nulls as -0? I have doubts about it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sorry, I can't track this knowledge to it's source, but found some trail of this opinion in google: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/204752/232279), [link2](http://www.orafaq.com/usenet/comp.databases.theory/2004/10/03/0069.htm), [link3](http://www.orafaq.com/usenet/comp.databases.theory/2005/01/21/0250.htm)

Comment: @ThinkJet Maybe it was true a long time ago -- I don't think it has been for quite some time if it ever was. Null numbers take up one byte of space in a row, which is just the marker for the new column, so there's no room in there for the representation of NULL as a number of any form.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Ok, I don't claim that it's the ultimate truth. Especially against modern versions. But at least number normalization must take place and zero always presented with positive sign to simplify arithmetic and comparison.

Comment: Some interesting links for research: [OTN discussion about `-0`](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2295515), [Article about numbers](http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/number_representation.htm), [infinity trick](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/08/positive-infinity.html), [Oracle v7 Concepts PDF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/pdf/A32534_1.pdf) - search here for "Internal Numeric Format" and "A null is the absence of a value" strings. It seems that "-0 is null" (if it true) must be traced to Oracle v5 times.